# JAVA Bin IO with Objects

Tags: java, object, io, binary

I'm having an issue reading and loading objects to and from a BIN file i keep getting the errors "java.io.WriteAbortedException" and "java.io.NotSerializableException". This is even when my Student object implements Serializable...

LOADER:

```
try{
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("students.dat");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  while(true){
   Student[] stu = null;
   int i = 0;
   try {
     stu = (Student[]) ois.readObject();
     studentBag.add(stu[i]);
   } catch (EOFException e) {
     break;
  }
   System.out.println(student);
   i++;
}
```

SAVER:

```
 Student[] studentArray = new Student[2];
studentArray[0] = student;   
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("students.dat", true);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(studentArray);
  oos.flush();
  oos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File not found");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Nope");
}
```

Yes I did close the try catches just didnt see a point in putting them here. 
Also im getting the errors at this line in the Loder stu = (Student[]) ois.readObject();

and this in the saver studentArray[0] = student;

Comment: `Student[]` isn't a `Loder`. Is every field in your `Student` **also** `Serializable`?

Comment: public class Student implements Serializable{
yah the student class implements it if thats what you mean

Comment: Even if your `Student` class implements `Serializable`, you still need to make sure that all of the fields in the `Student` class also are `Serializable`.

Comment: How do i make is so that they are?